# Как сместить элемент при уменьшении экрана браузера?

Tags: html, позиционирование, css

Есть картинка. В данном случае это смайл.

**Вот скриншот:**

[image]

Вот код:

```
.icons {
position: absolute;
bottom: 25%;
z-index: 1000;
left: 91.5%;
}
```

При уменьшении размера браузера, например, при сворачивании в окно (правый верхний угол, вторая кнопка от кнопки закрытия браузера) или при использовании портативного устройства с меньшим разрешением экрана, например, iPad или iPhone, данный смайлик смещается в правую часть.

**Скриншот сместившегося смайлика:**

[image]

Я понимаю, что при уменьшении размера экрана отсчёт `left: 91.5%;`идёт по-другому.
Но вот не могу додуматься, как обыграть так, чтобы смайлик сдвигался в специальное место, которое выделено под него.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить возникшую проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, нашёл выход. Через [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal), предположив, что максимальное разрешения экрана 1024 пикселей.

Answer (score 0):

jquery и/или js тебе помогут в этом.
Иными словами, делать надо самостоятельно. Фиксировать момент изменения размеров страницы, высчитывать новые относительные значения, менять значения в стилях.